# How to retain DataGrid group headers from scrolling in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

When a `DataGrid` is filled with many entries so that the vertical scrollbar appears, I don't want the `DataGrid` scroll viewer to hide the group headers. Instead, I want to have a `ScrollBar` per each *group*. In my case, there will always be just two (2) groups, so there will be 0-2 scrollbars.

Here's a minimalistic sample code: http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html#grouping

```
Customers = new ListCollectionView(_customers);
Customers.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Gender"));
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedCustomers}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander>
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                          <TextBlock Text="Items"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem occurs even in that basic example. I guess I need to use `ScrollViewer` somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your XAML to the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedCustomers}">
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander>
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                      <TextBlock Text="Items"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>

                                <ScrollViewer Height="100">
                                     <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ScrollViewer>

                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

You still need the DataGrid ScrollBar in-case your groups exceeded the available hight when expanded.

the result is something like this:

[image: Scroll Groups]

Comment: Can I somehow make the `ScrollViewer` to take the full height of its container, rather than hard coding to height of `100`? Remember I have 2 groups, always. So ideally, I would see them both taking 0-50% of vertical space. If they both are large, they both take 50%. If one is small the other is large, the other could take more (say 75% and 25%). For starters it would be nice to get rid of hard coded `100` values though.

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily, because you want to change the behavior of how the `ItemPresenter` presents the `DataGrid` items in their container. Instead, and as long as you have only two groups why don't change your implementation to another simlpler one.

Comment: You can use a normal `Grid` with two * height rows, on each row you can have an `ItemsControl` that binds to a collection that contains the items of a group.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ScrollViewer` to wrap the `ItemsPresenter` in `Expander`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsPresenter />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Maybe you have to disable the `VerticalScrollBar` for `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

Comment: sounds good but.... where do you put the datagrid, does it go inside the scrollviewer?