# Prevent datagrid group header from horizontally scrolling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, scroll, grouping

Just checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361791/how-to-retain-datagrid-group-headers-from-scrolling-in-wpf) out and it's very similar, but for vertical scrolling not horizontal.

I have a datagrid with grouped data, looks like this:

[image]

I just want to keep the group header information visible as I scroll horizontally across through the columns. But the header scrolls off the window:

[image]

Here's the xaml (originally from [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#grouping)), only for the datagrid group style... if you need more of it lemme know!

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ReferralDate}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupItem}}, 
                                            Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=groupTitleVisitsConverter}}" 
                                            Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: I have the same issue but haven't yet found an answer after quite some research. Did you fix this?

Comment: No unfortunately. Just leaving it as is... I might check out some third party controls though, maybe the extended WPF toolkit datagrid might do it?

Comment: I was just googling for the same thing and stumbled across this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5165488/Prevent-WPF-DataGrid-Auto-scrolling-Due-to-Clickin - not particularly elegant but also not overly complicated and might just work? The essence of that solution is to reset the scroll offset if scrolling happens within x milliseconds of clicking into a cell.